# Score is stuck at one

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im making a game where if the cat hits the mouse and it dies the score should go up with +1. The first time a mouse is killed, it counts it but the other 2 times (I have 3 mouses) he still says the score is only one.

this is the code in my enemymouse.ts file. I have a function hitmouse() where the lives are minus 1 and if the lives of the mouse are zero the mouse dies (killmouse()). Everytime a mouse is killed it should add a +1 to the score but this only works once.

```js
public lives : number = 300
    public score : number = 0

        public killMouse() : void {
            this.div.classList.add("dead") 
            this.score ++
        }

        public hitMouse() : void {
        this.lives --

           if (this.lives == 0) {
               this.lives = 300
               this.killMouse()
               console.log("dit is de score:")
               console.log(this.score) 
           }      
        }
```

This is my code from the game.ts file. Everytime a mouse collides with the cat it uses the hitmouse() function.

```js
    private gameLoop() : void {
        // update the mouse
        for (const entity of this.entity) {
            entity.update()

            if(this.checkCollision(entity.getBoundingRect(), this.cat.getBoundingRect())) {
                entity.hitMouse()
            }
        }
        // update the cat
        this.cat.update()

        requestAnimationFrame(() => this.gameLoop())
    }
```

Comment: Please create [mcve] instead of not runnable snippets

Comment: Why is the `score` in `enemymouse.ts` file? It should be in your `game.ts` file right?

Comment: why should it be in game.ts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your code, it seems when the hitMouse() is called for the first time, the value of this.lives becomes 0. So when you are calling hitMouse() for the second time, the value becomes -1. That's why you are not entering the if and the score remains 1. There must be a problem with the way you are handling 3 mice.

A simple way to make your game work would be to define lives variable as 3(for a mouse object) and every time hitMouse() is called, lives-- will be performed.

```
  public hitMouse() : void {
             if(this.lives > 0){
               this.lives --
               this.killMouse()
               console.log("dit is de score:")
               console.log(this.score) 
               }
```

}

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer! This seems to work (I now have a count that actually accounts above 1) but.......  Instead of counting to only 3 it counts to numbers above that, like it kills a mouse that is dead again.

Comment: I have modified my answer, it should work fine. Please accept my answer, thanks!